# Get list of include files from a specifc set of PHP source files

Tags: php

I need a script in PHP that will read other PHP source files and extract the file paths referenced in include, require and require once functions. I especially require this to create a deployment project so that the output package may only include files from the library folder which are used in project.

Are there any functions in PHP that can read source files and extract paths in require, include and require_once statements?

Comment: Please include the code you've tried and what went wrong. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Nothing went wrong. Just need an algorithm to parse source files and extract paths

Comment: Look into using [get_included_files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) somehow.

Comment: @brandon-wamboldt get_included_files cannot be used in this case because we are not including these files. Just trying to read and parse through file_get_contents.

Comment: @asim-ishaq I almost have a working version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proper answer, it actually parses PHP syntax. Please note, it's impossible to truly do what you want. For example, you may have auto loaders, or variable include paths which cannot be extracted automatically.

```
<?php
$required_file    = '';
$required_files   = array();
$is_required_file = false;

// Parse the PHP source using the Tokenizer library (PHP 4.3.0+)
$tokens           = token_get_all($text);

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    // Get the token name to make our code more readable.
    $token_name = is_int($token[0]) ? token_name($token[0]) : $token[0];

    echo $token[0]. ': ' . htmlentities($token[1]) . '<br>';

    // Is this token a require/include keyword?
    if (in_array($token_name, array('T_INCLUDE', 'T_INCLUDE_ONCE', 'T_REQUIRE', 'T_REQUIRE_ONCE'))) {
        $is_required_file = true;
    }

    elseif ($is_required_file && $token[0] != ';' && $token[0] != '.' && $token_name != 'T_WHITESPACE') {
        if ($token_name == 'T_STRING') {
            $token[1] = '{{CONST:' . $token[1] . '}}';
        }
        $required_file .= $token[1] ? trim($token[1], '\'"') : $token[0];
    }

    elseif ($is_required_file && $token[0] == ';') {
        $is_required_file = false;
        $required_files[] = trim($required_file, ' ()');
        $required_file    = '';
    }
}
```

`$required_files` is an array of the files. Matches `require`, `require_once`, `include` and `include_once`.

For the following input:

```
<?php
include APPLICATION_MODULES_ROOT . 'test1.php';
include($some_var . 'test55.php');
include('test2.php');
include ('test3.php');
include_once 'test4.php';
include_once('test5.php');
include_once ('test6.php');
require 'test7.php';
require('test8.php');
require ('test9.php');
//require ('test99.php');
require_once 'test10.php';
require_once('test11.php');
require_once ('test12.php');
```

You end up with this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {{CONST:APPLICATION_MODULES_ROOT}}test1.php
    [1] => test55.php
    [2] => test2.php
    [3] => test3.php
    [4] => test4.php
    [5] => test5.php
    [6] => test6.php
    [7] => test7.php
    [8] => test8.php
    [9] => test9.php
    [10] => test10.php
    [11] => test11.php
    [12] => test12.php
)
```

All you have to do is replace the constants your application uses, using str_replace or similar.

Important note: this does not work with variable include names, e.g. `include $some_path;`. You can't parse those.

Comment: I tried this also but this gives error: Warning: token_name() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in F:\dev\htdocs\package.php on line 378 The line 378 refers to: $token_name = token_name ( $token [0] );

Comment: @asim-ishaq Updating my code, one moment

Comment: I have further debuged this algorithm. The $token[0] often contains a number but not all the time. Some of the invalid values are as follows: , ; ) } { [ Can I add a check in code so that it checks $token[0] for a number and then process further?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php 
$source = file_get_contents('source.php');
preg_match_all('/(include|include_once|require|require_once) *\(? *[\'"](.*?)[\'"] *\)? *;/', $source, $matches);
$files = $matches[2];
```

`$files` is now an array of files that were included/required.

This isn't really a proper solution though, as it would match commented out code.

Comment: I tried this solution in project. It extract filenames for syntax like require("myfile.php"). My project have code like this for require (APPLICATION_MODULES_ROOT . "\\pages\\Screen.php"); But it does not read for my code. Let me try your other solution as well.

Comment: @asim-ishaq I see. My other example won't work for what you need either.